# Android : Speeding up multiple small file downloads

Tags: android, download, zip

I am hoping for some advice on how to speed up the download of multiple small files in my app.  The application downloads 300-400 small (15KB) files.  Even though the total size is small the downloads take a long time because of the  extra handshake time for each individual file..

I have tried to zip the file up, download it and unzip it on the device but in the end it was slower than simply downloading them all directly (though this could be due to an inefficient unzip algorithm..)

Can anyone give some advice on how to speed up the downloads (perhaps requesting to download 3 at a time rather than in sequence?) or have an efficient unzip snippet of code they don't mind sharing it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Even though the total size is small the downloads take a long time because of the extra handshake time for each individual file.

I am not quite certain how you made that determination. If it was via Traceview, great. If not, please consider using Traceview to determine exactly where slowdowns are.

Also, I am not quite certain what you mean by "handshake time". If you mean creating and tearing down socket connections, both `HttpUrlConnection` and `HttpClient` should support keep-alive. The former [has a bug in Android 2.1 and earlier](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html); the latter requires you to reuse your `HttpClient` instance.

As Mr. Gupta suggests, running a few requests in parallel is a reasonable move. You can use `AsyncTask`, perhaps with your own thread pool, so you can manage the parallel characteristics.

However, again, use Traceview to determine where your real problem lies.

Comment: I am currently simply using a UrlConnection.  It looks as though if I switch to an HttpUrlConnection, the keep-alive time will be very helpful.  I'll test this later tonight.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

The way browsers handle this is to start multiple threads to download resources in parallel. How may threads? Good question. I'm not sure, maybe you can use some kind of heuristics based of processor speed, number of cores and internet connection type - 2G, 3G, 4G etc. You could have a thread pool of this amount of threads worker threads that downloaded these files guaranteeing that you would never exceed a given number of threads.

Downloading the files sequentially definitely does not seem like the right way. `AsyncTask` is an ideal candidate for such jobs. If you don't know how to use that you could see [this](http://geekjamboree.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/asynctask-call-web-services-in-android/).

Comment: I am actually already using AsyncTask to do the downloads in the background.  However, I am calling a single AsyncTask which downloads the files sequentially.

So your recommendation would be to create multiple AsyncTasks to download multiple files at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is using a caching mechanism (assuming these files will be downloaded multiple times.) If you have to download these files individually, then yes, a separate request will always be made for each file and it will take as long as it needs to depending on your server/connection, etc.

If a user is going to have to download these files more than once, then caching these files would be best. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this interesting post on Android Developers blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

> In Gingerbread, we added transparent response compression.
>   `HttpURLConnection` will automatically add this header to outgoing
>   requests, and handle the corresponding response:
>
> `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
>
> Take advantage of this by configuring your Web server to compress
>   responses for clients that can support it.
>
> [...]
>
> For Gingerbread and better, `HttpURLConnection` is the best choice. Its
>   simple API and small size makes it great fit for Android. Transparent
>   compression and response caching reduce network use, improve speed and
>   save battery. New applications should use `HttpURLConnection`; [...]

Answer (score -1):

Do you generate the 300-400 files by yourself? Then you could make maybe 6 files each about 0.7 to 1 MB. Download them to your device. Then split them on a special String. This string also must be used when adding the files to a large one.

File1.txt:
This is the content of file 1!

File2.txt:
Here I am ;-)

Seperator:
{%~

Generated File should look like this:
File1.txt:This is the content of file 1!{%~File2.txt:Here I am ;-)

On the device you look for "{%~" and split is there.

Or you can use Threads to download more files at the same time.

Comment: I should have specified I am not creating these files myself.  Simply pulling them from the server.