# Android Socket download multiple files fired?

Tags: android, sockets, http-protocols

I want to download multiple images from server. I open socket and download first image and when I want download second image in this socket, download not proceed, socket are closed. My code below...

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(serverIpAddress, SERVERPORT);
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
            socket.connect(sockaddr, 5000);
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                final DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                final PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

                output.println("GET /way/images/profile/1231 HTTP/1.1");
                output.println("Host: 192.168.1.2");
                output.println("User-Agent: Java");
                output.println("Accept: */*");
                output.println("Connection: Keep-Alive");
                output.println("");
                output.flush();

                String line;
                File file = new File("/sdcard/aaa.png");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                System.out.println("Getting first file");
                while ( (line = input.readLine()) != null ) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    fileOut.write(line.getBytes());
                }
                System.out.println("First file finished");
                fileOut.flush();
                fileOut.close();

                output.println("GET /way/images/profile/1231 HTTP/1.1");
                output.println("Host: 192.168.1.2");
                output.println("User-Agent: Java");
                output.println("Accept: */*");
                output.println("Connection: Keep-Alive");
                output.println("");
                output.flush();

                file = new File("/sdcard/aaa1.png");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                System.out.println("Getting second file");
                while ( (line = input.readLine()) != null ) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    fileOut.write(line.getBytes());
                }
                System.out.println("Second file finished");

                fileOut.flush();
                fileOut.close();
                input.close();
                output.close();
                socket.close();
            }
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be downloading image files using HTTP, in which case, it would be simpler and better to use [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Code sample for downloading of images using `HttpURLConnection` can be found in this blog post: [Downloading image in Android](http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/01/downloading-image-in-android/)

You may also read about [Android's HTTP Clients](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) in Android Developers Blog.

Comment: I not use HttpURLConnection because, I not want every time open and close connection(in this process required many time, I want download files in one socket for saving of time).

Comment: Take a look at this question (and its answers) on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8913085/1321873

Comment: Thanks, but this post cant help me

Comment: Just to be sure that you did not miss the point, `HttpURLConnection` _may reuse the same underlying Socket for multiple request/response pairs_ as mentioned in the **Performance** section of the [documentaion](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).